# jQuery to remove mobile stylesheet onclick and preserve state via cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies, stylesheet

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to add a 'view full site' link to a mobile version of a site.  The mobile version is a limited version of the site and I'd like users to have the option of clicking a link and viewing the full site.    This is the best compromise I can come up with as the site is old and I can't rebuild it for responsiveness.  The mobile stylesheet has all the mobile styles wrapped in a media query based on device width.

So, I know I can remove a stylesheet with something like:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
```

But how do I specify a specific stylesheet?  Can I add an ID to the mobile stylesheet and target that?  How would I trigger this from a link?

The mobile style sheet is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/scripts/small_devices.css" />
```

Also, any tips on preserving this state via a cookie?  I'm totally baffled by this for some reason.

Any tips appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I think I've figured this out:

I added an ID to the mobile style like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" id="mobileSheet" href="small_devices.css" />
```

And then added the fallowing script and html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#removeStyle").click(function () {                           
    jQuery('#mobileSheet').remove();
    });
});

<p id="removeStyle">View Full Site</p>
```

This seems to work OK.  I'm still not sure how to drop a cookie to preserve this state - but at least this is the answer to the first part of my question.

Comment: I should add that I also figured out the cookie.  Used the jquery.cookie plug in and the following script.

$("#removeStyle").click(function () {  
 $('#mobileSheet').remove();
 $.cookie("prefFullSite", "showFull");
 });


if ($.cookie("prefFullSite"))
{$('#mobileSheet').remove();}
});